# Migrate a hand-made kubernetes cluster to kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have an existing production kubernetes cluster that was installed by hand, and for easier administration, I would like to upgrade it to a `kubeadm` installation. I know this will be hard and painful, but it will be easier for future admin.

Where should I start searching for a way to achieve this? Thanks.